# rounded corner fallback without javascript

Tags: css

what css workaround that you folks use to fallback support for ie6, 7,8  ? i need rounded corner for

1. text inside div (button)
2. image as background-image in div (make the image rounded corner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I know would be to use background images which often require extra markup. Myself I use CSS3PIE and leave the corners square when js is disabled

Answer (score 2):

Well search for [PIE(Progressive Internet Explorer)](http://css3pie.com/) this will take care of rounded corner shadow and lots of there css3 feather for IE and it is extremely easy to use and 100% work's at least for me

Answer (score 1):

you can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) which bring you css3 rounded corners for ie. You can also visit microsoft's [Other Rounded Corners Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413%28VS.85%29.aspx).